# modulo question For a positive integer $k$, does $\{x^2 \pmod k \mid x \in\mathbb Z\} = \{x \pmod k \mid x \in\mathbb Z\} $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

For a positive integer $k$, does $\{x^2 \pmod k \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\} = \{x \pmod k \mid x \in \mathbb{Z}\} $ ?

Comment: For a positive integer $k$, when are all the elements of $\Bbb Z_k$ quadratic residues modulo $k$?

Comment: I don't understand.  Suppose $k=3$.  Is your claim correct then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is equivalent to ask does $\{x^2 \pmod k | x \in Z\} =\{0,...,k-1\}$. This is obviously false, take $k=3$, we have no $x$ s.t. $x^2 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

In fact, given a non-zero $n$ and an odd prime $p$, [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) tells us that ${\displaystyle n}$ has a square root (i.e., ${\displaystyle n}$ is a quadratic residue) if and only if:
$$
{\displaystyle n^{\frac {p-1}{2}}\equiv 1{\pmod {p}}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

In order to have $\{0^2,1^2,2^2,\cdots,(k-1)^2\}=\{0,1,2,\cdots ,k-1\}$ we need that $x\to x^2$ be a bijection.

This is possible only when $k=2$ because $x^2=(-x)^2$. It is possible for $k=2$ because $1\equiv -1\pmod2$.